# Batch convert white background to transparent

Tags: macos, imagemagick, batch-processing, alpha-transparency

Seeking to set a folder of PNG line drawings to background transparent and getting lost in examples and options recommended for other cases. Essentially when I find a line of command that seems to fit I don't know how to apply it to an entire folder. Also getting lost in options like fuzz and anti-alias which I'm not even sure would benefit my images, below. I'm on a Mac running v7 of Magick and really appreciate your kind help.

[Simplest Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh7wx.jpg)

[Most Complex Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLGr5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want in Imagemagick 7. You should use magick mogrify to process a whole folder of images. To convert white to transparent in an image you can use -fuzz XX% -transparent white, where XX is a percent tolerance for nearby colors. For JPG, typically about 15% seems to work due to jpg compression change of flat colors. So I put your images into a folder called drawings and create a new empty folder called drawings2 to hold the output image, which need to be PNG (or TIFF) so use transparency.

```
cd
cd desktop/drawings
magick mogrify -path ../drawings2 -format png -fuzz 15% -transparent white *.jpg
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#mogrify

Comment: Thanks so much for your generous repl.! I'm eager to try it! I wonder though...does it change your script at all if I'm starting with PNGs?

Comment: If you start with PNG, you can eliminate the -fuzz XX% or use -fuzz 0. Try one image and see what fuzz value you need for it. Then do all of them with that fuzz value. Also change *.jpg to *.png or * if you want to process all the files in the folder (jpg, png, etc)

Comment: You couldn't make it any easier; thank you. Unfortunately I got back a Home-brew .zprofile error, need to run it down before I can see this in action. I'll report back when I have.